# Is it possible to pass a variable declared in a PUG/JADE file to the server side?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, body-parser

The title says it all. I want to be able to declare a counter variable in the client side and pass that value back to the server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> declare a counter variable in the client side and pass that value back to the server side

I'm not sure whether that is something you'd actually want: The template files never 'leave' the server side. Pug template files are compiled by the pug engine into static HTML files, which are served to the client.

Any values you want to pass from client to server should be sent through HTTP requests or other forms of web-communication, with static Javascript. In the case of HTTP requests, you would create an endpoint on your server which would accept new counter values and make an Ajax request to your server on the client-side.